# How can I hide the blue border in visual stdio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I click a component in the visual studio code interface, a blue border will appear around the component. How can I hide the blue border.

[image: Visual Studio Interface]

Comment: most likely it is the `focus` color of the theme, look for such colors in the theme colors and customize it for this theme in `settings.json`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your **settings.json** file and add the below property with color code (along with opacity level) :

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations":{
    "focusBorder":"#ff000000"
},
```

Please note the 2 extra 0's at the end in the color code. These are to set the opacity level. In this case its set to transparent which is what you want.

So now you won't be seeing any border around any component.

**EDIT 1 : START**

Elaborating on rioV8's comment: In case you want to customize the border for individual components, you can do so with help of rich [configuration settings for color theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color) provided by the VSCode.

**EDIT 1 : END**

Comment: Thanks a lot. The border has been annoying for me for years